# How to use GAP/magma to list all the elements of some order in a finite group?

Tags: gap, computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

How to use GAP/magma to list all the elements of some order in a finite group?
For example, let $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_{24}$, how to use GAP/magma to list all the elements of order $24$?

Comment: You may find the Software Carpentry-style lesson on GAP useful - in particular, see `AsList` at https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/01-command-line/

Comment: This is something you should be able to figure out easily from the documentation. Do you know how to iterate over group elements? How to check the order of an element? How to print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gap> group:=CyclicGroup(24);
<pc group of size 24 with 4 generators>
gap> elems:=Filtered(Elements(group),x->Order(x)=24);
[ f1, f1*f3, f1*f2*f3, f1*f2*f4, f1*f3*f4, f1*f4^2, f1*f2*f4^2, f1*f2*f3*f4^2 ]
```